# Why ArgumentException from Directory.Exist can not be catched?

Tags: c#, exception

Why I can't catch the Argument excpetion here:

```
        string path = "\"";
        bool dirOk = true;
        try
        {
            dirOk = Directory.Exists(path);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            dirOk = false;//Never gets in here
        }
```

Edited: Sorry, bad sample path, changed now!

Config VS debugger to halt on all exceptions.VS will break saying: "ArgumentException  Occurred" "Illegal characters in path.", but the try catch do nothing.

---

Edit 2: I think I got it, sorry. **VS breaks but the exception is already catch inside Exists().**

Comment: Did you look what the actual exception is?

Comment: because "invalid dir input" dir doesn't exist, and method return false

Comment: Sorry, bad sample patch, try this now: "\"". See the edit.

Comment: Your edit-code also fails to provide the exception...  Do you test this before posting?

Comment: please, config VS to break on all exceptions. VS will break.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The posted code does not throw any exception...

`Directory.Exists("nonsense string")` just returns `false`.

As far as I can tell it even returns when the string contains invalid path characters or is `null`.

On the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) there is no mention of exceptions so I assume this is  very 'safe' method to call.

The page does have this to say:

> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file.

Comment: Sorry, bad sample patch, try this now: "\"".

Comment: Yeah, but why VS breaks??

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yeah, if you pick nits. Normally there is an section __Exceptions__ with a table. Standard MSDN issue. That section is missing for the `Exists()` method.

Comment: I just want to understand why VS breaks when configured to break on all exceptions. Hmm.. Probably there is a try catch inside Exists().

Comment: @Pedro77 - VS behavior and program behavior are very different things. You have "Just my code" turned off, amongst others. There will be exceptions handled _inside_ this method. That does not match your question.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because `Directory.Exists` does not throw exception when the path is not valid, it only returns `true` or `false` depending on the existance of the directory.

Look in the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.Exists(string path)` is not throwing exceptions at all. This seems to be a classic RTFM case ;)

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) the method just returns false on any parameter that is not specifying an absolute or relative path.

Comment: Just see my edit. I was confused because VS was breaking. RTFE case.